# not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Tags: python, clase

Tengo un código en Python que lee un archivo .txt con el siguiente formato:

```
7 3 90
55 63 3 45
14 58 5 23
31 18 1 22
18 54 6 18
22 25 7 11
21 29 4 7
19 36 2 0
```

En donde los valores de la primera línea se guardan en las variables `n`, `p` y `sum`.
De la segunda línea en adelante se guardan los valores en una clase, en donde el primero es `x`, seguido por `y`, `pos` y por último `dist`.
Sin embargo, al leer el archivo me sale el error: `not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)` en el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
def extract_values(line):
    a, b, c = line.split()
    return int(a), int(b), int(c)
```

Adjunto el código completo:

```
#reading the file parameters
fileName = open('outputfile1LS.txt','r')

main_array = []

class Array:
    def __init__(self, x, y, pos):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pos = pos
        self.dist = dist

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} : {} : {} : {}'.format(self.x, self.y, self.pos, self.dist)

#converting the parameters intro int variables
def extract_values(line):
    a, b, c = line.split()
    return int(a), int(b), int(c)

with open('outputfile1LS.txt','r') as file:
    main_array = []

    n, p, sum = extract_values(file.readline())
    for line in file.readlines():
        x, y, pos, dist = extract_values(line)
        main_array.append(Array(x, y, pos, dist))

#----LOCAL SEARCH MOVE----
print(main_array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas que podrían mejorarse de tu código, por ejemplo, la variable **fileName** no es utilizada, en todo caso podrías ponerle el nombre del archivo para ser utilizada en en **with open**

Pero referente a tu pregunta, creo que la manera de resolverlo con la menor cantidad de cambios es la siguiente

Agregar dist a los parámetros que necesitas para instanciar un objeto de la clase, si no haces esto, tu código tronará aunque leas bien los valores de la línea

Agregar una condición de longitud en la función extract_values, de esta forma puedes controlar qué hacer de acuerdo a la longitud de los valores de la línea

De manera que el código entero queda de la siguiente manera:

```
#reading the file parameters
fileName = 'outputfile1LS.txt'

main_array = []

class Array:
    def __init__(self, x, y, pos, dist):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pos = pos
        self.dist = dist

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} : {} : {} : {}'.format(self.x, self.y, self.pos, self.dist)

#converting the parameters intro int variables
def extract_values(line):
    values = line.split()

    if(len(values) == 3):
        return int(values[0]), int(values[1]), int(values[2])  

    else:
        return int(values[0]), int(values[1]), int(values[2]), int(values[3])

with open(fileName,'r') as file:
    main_array = []

    n, p, sum = extract_values(file.readline())
    for line in file.readlines():
        x, y, pos, dist = extract_values(line)
        main_array.append(Array(x, y, pos, dist))

#----LOCAL SEARCH MOVE----
print(main_array)
```

Este código, con los valores del archivo que compartiste, da el siguiente resultado:

```
[55 : 63 : 3 : 45, 14 : 58 : 5 : 23, 31 : 18 : 1 : 22, 18 : 54 : 6 : 18, 22 : 25 : 7 : 11, 21 : 29 : 4 : 7, 19 : 36 : 2 : 0]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.